# How to Handle High Sized Images with Glide without OutofMemoryError?

Tags: android, json, image, android-glide

I have a JSON output with image fields. Every image(approx. 120) is around 500-700 KB. When I call API via Retrofit, my app is giving `OutofMemory` error and crashing as I try to load every image at the same time. How do I handle this process? I tried `preload` and  `downloadonly` from Glide, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for more memory than you can have.

So.. Reduce the memory you're asking for.
Don't load images that are 4k resolution, downscale them to 1080px at MAX.
Why on earth are you trying to show 120 images at once?

Glide as built in scaling support, so you can ask it to give you a specific size of an image.